# Late answer indicates that the code in the question is plagiarized

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I recently went to fix a [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44855145/4131059) that was of very low quality, with bad formatting and erratic capitalization all over the place. I was about to recommend deletion until I careful read it, and notice that they accurately determine the source code written by the OP is actually plagiarized verbatim from an [example](https://github.com/LuizGsa21/intro-to-java-10th-edition/blob/master/src/Chapter_12/Exercise_15.java) here. In fact, there are no differences whatsoever in between the original code and the example they claim to have "made": even the original attribution in the comments of the example is intact.

What's the appropriate response here? Should I recommend that the original question is closed? Should I delete the answer and flag the question?

Comment: well the answer is still inappropriate as an answer, even if it's right. The A should be deleted (as it's not an A), but the Q should be flagged, if it's truly violating some license

Comment: Just asking about code that was written by someone else isn't in itself a reason for closure, if the code is freely reusable, for example. If there's truly a licensing issue, we should probably move directly to deletion.

Comment: The issue I have is that the OP says "I made this..." and then posts code that was not written by them, and even has attribution of another author in the comments of the code. The code is verbatim to an example from another link. @JoshCaswell

Comment: Sure, that's crappy,  but if we remove that via an edit, like we would any other irrelevancies, is it or is it not a good, on-topic question that's going to help other people?

Comment: Not a heckofalot of intentional plagiarism at work when he quotes "Chapter 12 Exercise 15".  Newbie programmers do get stuck on working through the exercises of a book all the time, we do next hear from them.  Because of their own code, not somebody else's, nothing getting plagiarized.  I think I see somebody that will turn into a highly skilled professional some day, just needs a bit of help to get there.  He doesn't need a snarky answer.

Comment: I dunno @HansPassant, I consider copying someone else's example without any modification of any form (even from your assigned textbook) and saying "I made this but am so aggravated since I am unable to make a couple of simple statements." to be plagiarism of some form. Probably just edit the question then?

Comment: The problem isn't so much that this is plagiarism (which can easily be resolved by editing "I made this" to "I found this" or "I don't understand this" or whatever), but that it is (as far as we know) a copyright violation, unless the question author has a private license agreement with the code author that we don't know about.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If a question is copied word-for-word from another question, flag it and we'll deal with it. That isn't quite what's going on here, though.

First off, that answer wasn't really an answer, so I deleted it. Feel free to flag something like that as "not an answer" in the future.

When it comes to the code in the question, it does include a comment stating its origin ("Created by Luiz Arantes Sa", etc.), so they're not exactly hiding where this came from. Is it disingenuous to state "I made this"? Sure, but maybe that was a mistranslation and they meant to say something like "I'm trying to use this code I found". I'm not sure that the intent was to fully take credit for that code.

While copied words are easy to identify as plagiarism, it's a little trickier to label code as being plagiarized. I'm more likely to do so for an answer, where someone is presenting code they got from somewhere else as a solution, than in a question, where someone is asking about a piece of code.

The real problem is the question itself, where they provide no indication of what's wrong in their attempt. If we don't know what the problem is with that code or whatever they attempted, how can we provide them with a solution? Therefore, I closed it.

Comment: Why wasn't that answer converted into a comment? It seems worthy of such.

Comment: "Maybe that was a mistranslation" -- Yes. In some languages, the same verb is used for situations where we would use "did" in English, as for "made." So it's very plausible that the OP meant "I did this" - which could mean anything, including "I tried to compile this example" -  and didn't intend to claim he or she had written the code from scratch.

Comment: Also, what exactly does "this" refer to? Is it a specific customization to the code? The entire code block? The entire web page? The entire github site? The entire Stackoverflow site?